# Raspberry Pi mouse and keyboard not working

Tags: pi-3b+, keyboard, mouse

So last night I was using my Raspberry Pi just fine but my internet didn't work so i fixed it with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

This morning I plugged it in and neither the mouse nor keyboard work, they are getting power, as they have lights on them but aren't working. I went to recovery mode and they work just fine but not in the desktop.

Also my Raspberry Pi sometimes after booting just shows a black screen, which also started this morning.

Comment: Sounds like a power issue, try switching PSU and Micro USB cable. Check the log with the command `dmesg` after any error messages, https://www.tecmint.com/dmesg-commands/.

Comment: I did, same thing, it's not a power issue as they work in recovery mode

Comment: What operating system you are using? What is recovery mode?

Comment: maybe try pushing the cord (or connector, in my case.) more into the pi. and for the black screen, just wiggle the mouse

Comment: @Annelies *"they are getting power, as they have lights on them but aren't working"*